# Convert a dataframe column of dictionaries with lists into separate columns with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with one of the columns as a list and another column as a dictionary. However, this is not consistent. It could be a single element or NULL too. Also, they are parsed as string type. The dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[1,2,3,4],
'shop_id':[['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4'],'S2','S3',['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']], 
'price':[{'10':['S1','S2'], '20':['S3'], '30':['S4']},'50','NaN',{'10':['S1','S2','S3'],'25':['S4']}]})
```

```
+-------+---------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Index | item_id |     shop_id        |                      price                         |
+-------+---------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|     0 |       1 | '[S1, S2, S3, S4]' | '{'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']}' |
|     1 |       2 | 'S2'               | '50'                                               |
|     2 |       3 | 'S3'               | 'NaN'                                              |
|     3 |       4 | '[S1, S2, S3, S4]' | '{'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']}'         |
+-------+---------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like this to be expanded as this:

```
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
| Index | item_id | shop_id | price |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
|     0 |       1 | S1      | 10    |
|     1 |       1 | S2      | 10    |
|     2 |       1 | S3      | 20    |
|     3 |       1 | S4      | 30    |
|     4 |       2 | S2      | 50    |
|     5 |       3 | S3      | NaN   |
|     6 |       4 | S1      | 10    |
|     7 |       4 | S2      | 10    |
|     8 |       4 | S3      | 10    |
|     9 |       4 | S4      | 25    |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are we guaranteed no S value in the dictionary values will map to more than one value?

Comment: @ Henry Ecker. Yes. That's guaranteed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `apply` and `explode`:

```
df['price'] = [[i for i in d.keys() for x in d[i]] if isinstance(d, dict) else [d] for d in df['price'].tolist()]
df = df.set_index('item_id').apply(pd.Series.explode, axis=0).reset_index()
print(df)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Would give:

```
   item_id shop_id price
0        1      S1    10
1        1      S2    10
2        1      S3    20
3        1      S4    30
4        2      S2    50
5        3      S3   NaN
6        4      S1    10
7        4      S2    10
8        4      S3    10
9        4      S4    25
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. This doesn't work as expected since the values are parsed as strings and not as dictionaries. Also, there are single entries that are strings or NaN and throws AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'. Could you please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: The eval part doesn't work because there are individual entries that are not lists/dicts. Also the NaNs/NULLs need to be considered. The same thing causes the key issue

Comment: I'm sorry but the single string entries like '50' cause the attribute error as I mentioned before - 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: @charlie_boy it's a typo, definitely should work now

Comment: I appreciate your effort but could you please try with the data frame I've given? It still throws the errors as I mentioned Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have a partial solution for you and a question.

The piece of code I have for this is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    "item_id" : [1, 2, 3, 4] , 
    "shop_id" : [['S1','S2','S3','S4'], "S2", "S3", ['S1','S2','S3','S4']],
    "price" : [{'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']}, 50, np.nan, {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']}] })
df1 = df1.explode('shop_id')
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

|  | item_id | shop_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | S1 | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
| 1 | 1 | S2 | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
| 2 | 1 | S3 | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
| 3 | 1 | S4 | {'10': ['S1', 'S2'], '20': ['S3'], '30': ['S4']} |
| 4 | 2 | S2 | 50 |
| 5 | 3 | S3 | nan |
| 6 | 4 | S1 | {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']} |
| 7 | 4 | S2 | {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']} |
| 8 | 4 | S3 | {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']} |
| 9 | 4 | S4 | {'10': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], '25': ['S4']} |

For the price column can you do a lookup to a different table based on shop_id and item_id? If not I can keep trying to come up with a solution.

Comment: Thanks! explode definitely helps but I would like to expand the data frame into the final format as I mentioned. This is the tricky part I'd like to resolve. Appreciate your help :)